# Spring Boot HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-boot

I am currently racking my head as to why including a parameter @RequestBody Car car breaks my end point.

I am very new to Spring boot and and trying to post a json string to my rest controller.

Here's my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/car")
@EnableWebMvc
public class CarController  {

private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(CarController.class);

@Autowired
private CarService carService;


@RequestMapping(value="/{accountId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"text/plain", "application/*"})
ResponseEntity<?> start(@PathVariable final Integer accountId, @RequestBody Car car) {
    System.out.println("E: "+accountId);
    final long tid = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    final Boolean status = this.smarterWorkFlowService.startWorkFlow(accountId, car);
    return new ResponseEntity<Car>(new Car(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED); 
}
}
```

I am using jackson as my json parser too. I looked for hours and have found nothing that can help me explain why I am getting a response of 415 back.

`{
    "timestamp": 1425341476013,
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "path": "/v1/experiences/12"
}`

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 3):

First, in spring boot `@EnableWebMvc` is not needed. Then, if your REST service need to produce json or xml use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "properties", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Test your service

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Content-type", header);
headers.add("Accept", header);

UIProperty uiProperty = new UIProperty();
uiProperty.setPassword("emelendez");
uiProperty.setUser("emelendez");

HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(uiProperty, headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/properties/1", HttpMethod.POST, entity,String.class);
return response.getBody();
```

Replace header by `application/json` or `application/xml`. If you are usin xml, add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! The service only needs to produce JSON. I did add the produces parameter, but still get the 415 error when I test the POSTMan chrome app. My rest service need to accept POST methods though. I have verified I am sending the right content type.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update my question, Now you can try with a few changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JSON, remove the `consumes={...}` part of your `@RequestMapping`, make sure you're actually POSTing JSON and set the `Content-type` to `application/json`.